# Using python to find the file size of files on a ftp

Tags: python, ftp, filesize

I'm new to python and I'm trying to read an ftp directory and write the filenames and file sizes to a file (currently a text file)

```
import sys
import os
import ftplib
import ftputil
import fnmatch
log = open("C:/..../ftp_name.txt","a")
print "logging into FTP" # print 
host = ftputil.FTPHost('address','Uname','Pass') # ftp host info
recursive = host.walk("/WORLDVIEW",topdown=True,onerror=None) # recursive search 
for root,dirs,files in recursive:
    for name in files:
        fullpath = os.path.join(root, name)
        size = FTP.size(fullpath)
        writepath = fullpath + " " +size + "\n"
        log.write(writepath)
```

I got it to write the filename and path but once I added the size function in it went wrong

The error I received was:

```
<b>NameError: name 'FTP' is not defined</b>
```

I have also tried replacing

```
size = FTP.size(fullpath)
```

with

```
size = recursive.size(fullpath)
```

which returned the error:

```
<b>AttributeError: 'generator' object has no attribute 'size'</b>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally to get file size you use the `os` module: https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.getsize.

When using `ftputil` they make that an equivlant call of `host.path.getsize`

You can view more of the documentation for it here: http://mcdc.missouri.edu/libs/python/ftputil/ftputil.html#retrieving-information-about-directories-files-and-links

```
   ...
   for root,dirs,files in recursive: 
       for name in files: 
           fullpath = host.path.join(root, name)
           size = host.path.getsize(fullpath)
```

Comment: Hi, I also tried that but I received this error:     <b>WindowsError: [Error 3] The system cannot find the path specified: '/WORLDVIEW/...21075\\LABEL.txt'</b> I'm not sure where the double slash came from

Comment: I updated the answer to use ftputil, hopefully that works for you!

Comment: Hmm my error just became a lot more complex after updating the code! **  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\ftputil\ftp_stat.py", line 452, in _real_lstat
    "550 %s: no such file or directory" % path)
ftputil.ftp_error.PermanentError: 550 /WORLDVIEW/DEVI/DEVI_FIN_I027161_21075\LAB
EL.txt: no such file or directory
Debugging info: ftputil 2.2.3, Python 2.7.3 (win32)**     that's the end of the error. I suppose I need to play around with the path as it places a \ ahead of label.txt instead of /?

Comment: You are correct the error is the last "\" is different than all the "/"s before it. Basically FTP using unix folder structure, and when you call "os.path.join" it automatically joins using the systems default, which in your case is windows. Use `host.path.join` instead.

Comment: Great to hear, please accept the answer if it's working for you as is :)

Answer (score 1):

I know you got an answer but

size = FTP.size(fullpath) FALSE maybe you copied it from https://docs.python.org/2/library/ftplib.html

You see all of the functions have FTP.function() it just a headline

try using

size = ftp.size(fullpath)

am amazed no one pointed that out for almost 3 years

NameError: name 'FTP' is not defined === check the name

I know because I had the same error.

Comment: Yep... you're right, except he called his ftp connection host, so it would be host.size(fullpath)     Working for me